# Handling multiple TimerTasks with one Timer

Tags: java, timer, timertask

With one `TimerTask`, everything looks pretty straightforward and works fine.
But I can not handle different 'TimerTasks' within one Timer.
I tried adding TimerTask object into the constructor but have an compilation error when I pass new TimerTask (RemindTask1) object as a parameter (instance of inner class).

Here is how it works with one task:

```
public class MyTimer {
    Timer timer;

    public MyTimer(long time) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), time);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /// ...
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /// ...
        MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer(5000);
        /// ...
    }
}
```

But I am completely stuck with how multiple tasks should be created and then run.

```
public class MyTimer {
    Timer timer;

    public MyTimer(TimerTask tt, long time) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(tt, time);
    }

    class RemindTask1 extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /// ...
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    class RemindTask2 extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /// ...
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /// ...
        MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer(new RemindTask2(), 5000);
        /// ...
    }
}
```

But that's not working and I can't figure out what's wrong.
I am having an compilation error when I pass new RemindTask2() as a parameter.

Comment: Instead of doing all the work in the constructor, create a public method in the MyTimer class, and move the scheduling of the task to the body of that method.  Just like a constructor, a method can accept a TimerTask argument.

Comment: I reworded some parts of your question and gave you a more descriptive title (something that someone searching for your question would use). Right now it's not completely clear what's wrong, so it might be better if you added some more information about what you are looking to do within the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks fot your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by "not working" you mean the compiler isn't letting you create an instance of the inner class `RemindTask2` from a static context (`main` method).

There are generally two ways to handle this.

1. Ask a `MyTimer` instance to create its inner class instance for you. This actually isn't an option for you since you need the inner class instance to exist *before* you construct the `MyTimer`.

```
    MyTimer myTimer;
    // initialize myTimer
    TimerTask task = myTimer.new RemindTask2();
```

2. Change the inner classes to nested classes by adding the `static` keyword. This is the option for you.

```
    static class RemindTask2 extends TimerTask {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Pretty easy solution and works fine. One more question is how to cancel timer task here, not the timer itself?

Comment: You don't need to cancel the timer there unless you want to make sure the task executes only once. The task ends when the `run()` method finishes executing, so there's no need to "cancel" the task itself. Besides there's no point in canceling only the task, when the `MyTimer` instance exists for the sole purpose of running that one task.